# Having form send to Javascript thento php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, variables

So i have been getting help from another question on here but i need some help getting this code to work

What i am trying to do is have the form send the "count" var to JS so that it can do a for loop a user specified amount of times and also have it send the other 2 variables to php for it to process the form data.

But I am new to javascript so i dont know how i could accomplish this.

here is the code for the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html> 
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        color: #FF0000;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
   .style7 {color: #FF0000}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#Submit").click(function(){
var count = form.count.value;
var number = 0
              for (i=1;i<=#count;i++)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"process.php",
                type:"get",
                data:$("form").serialize(),
                success:function(response){
                    number++
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
                    var success = obj.success;
                    var actionsNumber = obj.number;
                    $("#result").html('<b>'+number+'</b>');                     
                }
            })
}
        })
    })
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <center> <p>
    <label><b><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>Page</big></big></big></big>  </big>        </big></big></b></label>
    </p>
<p>
<p>
<label><strong>MN</label>
</p>
<input name="MN" type="text" value=""/>
</p>
<p>
<p>
<label><strong>Number to Send</label>
</p>
<input name="count" type="text" value = "1"/>
 <input name = "number" type = "hidden" value = "$number"/>
</p>
<p>
<p>
<label><strong>Provider</label>
</p>
<select name="provider">
    <option value="">Choose One...</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<input id="Submit" type = "button" value = "Send">
</p>
<p>You have done <span id="result">0</span> actions</p>
</center>
</body></html>
```

and this is process.php

```
<?php session_start();
// process your form data as you do 
//:::::::::
//
if(!isset($_SESSION['number'])){
  $_SESSION['number'] = 0;
 }
$number =  $_SESSION['number']++;
sleep(.5);
// output json response 
echo'{"success":"true","number":"'.$number.'"}';
?>
```

so I need `for (i=1;i<=#count;i++)` to work with the number the user puts in the "count" field and I also need `process.php` to get the stuff from the other boxes.

any help?

Comment: #count doesn't mean anything. you declared count so that's the variable you need to use in your loop. If you use a browser like Chrome you can press ctrl+shift+j and then choose scripts. Now you can debug your js code with breakpoints. It should be erroring.

Comment: I know it is erroring, but how can i take the number entered in the "count" field and do the for loop that number of times?

Comment: You code has a lot of problems and it looks like you haven't bothered to try and debug it or you would be able to ask specific questions about it. Go to youtube.com and search for 'using chrome debugger.' Then step through your code and ask specific questions if you don't understand why something is not working as expected. Saying, 'This is broke fix it for me' is not what SO is supposed to be about.

Answer (score 0):

You can read out the number with $('#count').val(). Your codes looks a bit weird though. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: this isnt a full code, it accomplishes nothing except printing numbers for the amount of times inputed.

Comment: but why wont this work  var count = $('#count').val(); then for (i=1;i<=count;i++){

Comment: Well, that's hard to say. Looking at that piece of code it should work (maybe using the var identifier before the i variable makes some difference, but think not). Only thing I could think of than, is the the value of count is not an int or greater than 1 so the loop don't  get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to bind your click event to the correct element in the DOM. Your existing code looks like this...

```
$("#Submit").click(...);
```

`#Submit` refers to an element with `id="Submit"` -- which there isn't one on your page. What you should be doing is something more like this...

```
$('form').bind( 'submit', function( ){ ... } );
```

Now your form submission event is being properly captured, you just need to get the values out.

```
$('form').bind( 'submit', function( )
{
     var self = $(this); // -- reference to form element
     var count = self.find( 'input[name="count"]' );

     console.debug( count.val( )); // -- if you don't have a console, get one... or just use alert()
 } );
```

Comment: the thing is the whole code works fine without the count there(if there is a number there) the Submit refers to the button with the id "Submit"

Comment: `this` is a keyword and refers to the submit button (in this case) -- the code I provided should work exactly as is.